# MATLAB: One-hot matrix to histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, one-hot-encoding

I have a one-hot-encoded matrix (size `1E6 x 10`) where each row represents an observation and each column represents a category. How can I create a histogram to visualize the counts for each category and label the category names in the x-axis (I guess vertically positioned to prevent overlap) rather than just using the column numbers?

Comment: Wouldn't the histogram counts just be `sum(M, 1)`?

Comment: Hmm that gives a vector of totals, but not sure how to make a histogram out of that.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#bvl9b2c-1

Comment: given you're talking about 'labels' you don't need a 'histogram', you need a bar chart.

Comment: Ah I guess I should just use bar() thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your matrix is `M` you can get the row-wise sum, as beaker suggested, and use that to plot a bar chart. (since you're talking about labels it's unlikely you need a 'histogram' as such).

```
bar (sum (M, 1));
```

To set the labels to names, you can edit the resulting axes object's properties:

```
set (gca, 'xticklabel', {'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'});
```

If you're using Matlab 2014b or later, you can also control the rotation:

```
set (gca, 'xticklabelrotation', 90);
```

Comment: Or you can just pass the labels to `bar` as in the link I posted in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. I have to rotate the labels anyway I might as well do it this way.

Comment: @beaker my bad, sorry, I didn't even click that (I just assumed it was the generic bar reference page, didn't see the anchor). Having said that, I think converting to categorical is probably a bit overkill if the only use is going to be to serve as x labels.

Comment: Yup, and if you're going to rotate it anyway, might as well stay with `set`.